# URL structure preference - to slash or not to slash?

Tags: wordpress, url-rewriting, url-routing, friendly-url

I'm using custom post types in WordPress 3.0 to manage 'courses' (or seminars, lectures, whatever term you'd prefer to have in mind).

Now for viewing a single 'course', the url structure is;

```
/course/course-name/
```

But for multiple courses?

```
/courses/category/category-name/
```

Or...

```
/course-category/category-name/
```

Or something entirely different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From an SEO prespective **the least forward slashes the better**.
Every level (forward slash) you put means (usually) less importance to (some) search engines.

I'd recommend you to use Level-1 URLs like

`www.example.com/course-marketing-the-best-practices`

Or Level-2 as much.

> Search engines put less weight on indexing pages above 2nd levels. For example, the URL (http://pohee.com/Level-1/Level-2/Level-3), pages in "Level-3" level receives less focus by search engine crawler. *by Pohee*
>
> Search engine crawlers expect the important content to be found within the first two or three subfolders. *by GetInPosition*

Some resources:

- [SEO Tips: Ideal Folder Level In Website Hierarchy](http://pohee.com/it/seo/seo-tips-ideal-folder-level-in-website-hierarchy/)
- [SEO and Dynamic Websites - how do they fit together?](http://www.getinposition.com/articles/2006/11/seo_and_dynamic_websites_how_d.html)

Comment: Agreed. Sometimes it happens and for good reason, but that's typically for larger sites that already do a high volume of traffic. Burying your content by "adding slashes" means it's deeper and crawlers may not care to spider it unless they have a significant indication to do so, like it going hot on Digg or Reddit and receving a lot of inbound links.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just /courses/category-name/ ?

It is the course category after all.

Comment: I wanted that, but the client also wants to collate courses into 'groups', so I need to indicate in the URL if I'm querying a 'category' or a 'group' (two separate taxes in WP).